# Closing Receiver triggered splash screen (activity) opens main activity after closing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

[First app] I have a certain animated splash screen (activity) that gets opened via broadcast and can be closed either by a button on the activity itself or via another broadcast. Both opening and closing are working fine. However, whenever the splash screen is active (on screen) and I either deliver the broadcast or click the button, the activity does gets closed but brings my main (launcher) activity to the foreground. If I press the back button on splash screen it opens my main activity. If I press the home button and deliver the broadcast via a notification action then everything works normally.

If I open my app (i.e. launcher activity), press the back button and then deliver receiver to open the splash screen, then it does not open my main activity when closed. This means that my splash screen is always delivered at the top of my app stack. Is this behavior normal? I want to avoid this so, any workaround is welcome.

Code to launch splash screen :

```
private void showSplashScreen() {
    Intent m_intent = new Intent(this, SafSplashActivity.class);
    m_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    m_intent.putExtra("theme", theme);
    context.startActivity(m_intent);
}
```

**Update 1:**
If I use `System.exit(0)` in place of `finish(0)` in my splash activity, then instead of bringing my main activity to the foreground, my main activity gets started from scratch (and eventually brought into foreground)...

P.S. - This is a serious issue for my app because even after clicking the close button on splash screen if users find themselves on launcher activity they may get tempted to do a 'force-stop' of the app. This would be bad for the app as it is highly dependent on system triggered broadcasts which would then be blocked.

Comment: where you call finish(); ?

Comment: finish(); gets called either on button click in spash activity or inside the receiver registered locally at runtime in that activity when broadcast for closing is received.

Comment: Please check my update considering use of System.exit(0) in place of finish();

Comment: Just curious, was this a local broadcast receiver or global receiver in your splash activity?

Comment: @SQLiteNoob It was most definitely global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though its an old problem I asked, I ended up solving it by adding to my launch intent:

```
m_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

According to the docs:

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will
>   cause a newly launching task to be placed on top of the current home
>   activity task (if there is one).  That is, pressing back from the task
>   will always return the user to home even if that was not the last
>   activity they saw.

Since, my splash activity is a standalone one which is supposed to be launched even when the phone is locked so, the above flag fit perfectly. One downside is that the flag will only work on API 11+ (i.e. a total of 4 of my users will not benefit from it :D). Anyway, this seems to be much better than using a non-standard `launchMode`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by setting the `launchMode="singleInstance"` for the splash activity. Although, I am still not sure if the original issue was supposed to exist. What if singleInstance launch mode is not-usable in someone else's use case? What would be the solution then ?